# SlickGrid | Escaping Space | Formatter

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, slickgrid

I am using SlickGrid formatter.Below is my code

```
var columns = [{
    id: "name", 
    name: "name", 
    field: "name", 
    sortable: true,
    formatter: linkFormatter1
},];

var linkFormatter1 = function ( row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext ) {
    return "<a href=javascript:check1(\'" + dataContext['name'] + "\') class='listLink'>" + value + '</a>';
};

function check1(data){
    alert(data);
}
```

Consider my case where 'name' field is "Routing Type".It considers only 'Routing'.It omits Space.How can i escape single space.Let me know asap.thanks in adv.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not wrapping your `href` with quotes.  Try this:

```
var linkFormatter1 = function ( row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext ) {
    return '<a href="javascript:check1(\'' + dataContext['name'] + '\');" class="listLink">' + value + '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to escape all special characters automatically..i m getting correct in alert.the problem occurs when i send to spring controller.Is there any method to escape all special characters.. i tried java.util.regex.Pattern.quote((request.getParameter("name"))).but it is throwing SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet popup threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(Unknown Source)